# iPhone Configuration Utility for Windows Error

Tags: iphone, deployment

We are getting an error when deploying an iPhone application to iOS 4 using the Windows configuration Utility, 3.0.  The application loads great using the configuration utility on a mac, fails on windows.

We have confirmed that the provision is copied onto the device, it's just the app.

The error is:

> Could not install application on
>   device.  Error: A signed resource has
>   been added, modified, or deleted.

Several posts talked about special chars used on macs not working on the PC, we have been careful to only use allowed chars in the name of the app.

Any advice on this would be great, and yes, we suggested they buy a ton of macs already. :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. Finally manage to get around by installing my application using the windows version of iTunes . Forget the iphone configuration utility for installing apps. It's too buggy :(

Comment: +1 I wasted a bit of time deleting files from temp directories and so on, but the problem wouldn't go away. Then I tried iTunes and it worked perfectly.